# How to Write MSSQL Table Data to .Txt File Using PHP Then Send .Txt File to an Email

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, email

I am trying to create a PHP page that will select all data from my MSSQL table `products`. Once all data is selected I would like a `.txt` file to be created that displays all the table data in it. When the `.txt` file is created I would like the file to be attached to an email that gets sent to me. I prefer the `.txt` file to not be saved onto my website's server as that would create a lot of `.txt` files and take up too much space.

If anyone has any idea on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What you're describing isn't a simple matter of one or two lines of code.  I had to jump through hoops just to get PHP to talk to the MSSQL DB.  What have you tried?  Is it not working?  No one here is going to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide and conquer.

**Connecting to a MSSQL database in PHP**
http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

**PHP file IO functions**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

**PHP send email**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Once you've learned how to do each of these small tasks, you can integrate them into the larger system you've described.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dan. You put me on the right track!

Comment: @Michael You're welcome. Feel free to come back and ask a more specific question should you find yourself stuck somewhere along the way. Good luck!